# Refresh Flatlist React native

Tags: react-native, redux

I try to reload my feed in my flatlist with refreshControl. The scroll works fine, so if I scroll down the ActivityIndicator shows. But the problem is that the flatlist doesn't updates. Can any one see why or have a another solution to reload a flatlist?

This is my reload function:

```
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timeout));
    }

    const onRefresh = React.useCallback(() => {
        setRefreshing(true);
        props.reload()
        wait(2000).then(() => setRefreshing(false));
    }, []);
```

This is how I display it in my flatlist

```
     <FlatList
                    refreshControl={
                        <RefreshControl
                            refreshing={refreshing}
                            onRefresh={onRefresh}
                        />
                    }
                    numColumns={1}
                    horizontal={false}
                    data={filteredDataSource}
                    extraData={filteredDataSource}
                    renderItem={({ item }) =>
                    {My Items here}
                    />
                 }
```

in my Action.js (redux) I have I Function called reload()

```
export function reload() {
    return ((dispatch) => {
        dispatch(clearData())
        dispatch(fetchUsersData())
        dispatch(fetchUser())
        dispatch(fetchUserPosts())
        dispatch(fetchFollowingUsersPosts())
    })
}
```

Here I set my FilteredDataSource to my posts

```
    useEffect(() => {
        let posts = [];
        if (props.usersPostLoaded == props.allPosts.length) {
            for (let i = 0; i < props.allPosts.length; i++) {
                const user = props.users.find(el => el.uid === props.allPosts[i]);
                if (user != undefined) {
                    posts = [...posts, ...user.posts]
                }
            }
            posts.sort(function (x, y) {
                return x.creation - y.creation
            })

            setPosts(posts);
            setFilteredDataSource(posts);
            setMasterDataSource(posts);
        }
    }, [props.usersPostLoaded]);
```

Comment: on `clearData` how is the FlatList data prop state gets updated are you assigning any non-array type as default state? have you checked if the FlatList data state is updated with the new data?

Comment: probably you need to set extraData prop in the flatlist

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `extradata` prop in flatlist and your flatlist will refresh with change in that data.

`extraData={userData}`

https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#extradata

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the extraData, how do I get that? Is it one the same way that get my "orginaldata"?

Comment: `extraData` is a prop in Flatlist...you need to give the data for which you want the flatlist to re-render when the data changes.

Comment: You can give the same data that you are passing in `data` prop.

Comment: Mm okey, if I just copy and paste the data to extraData nothing happened. Should I do something more?

Comment: I added my flatlist in my question.

Comment: where are you setting your `filteredDataSource`?

Comment: I set my filteredDataSource in my useEffect there I set my posts to the user. I updated my question.

Comment: Here is my screen on github https://github.com/Alexanderjansson91/MusicFriend/blob/master/screens/Feed.js

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to Implementation it , usage from **useEffect** for control your life cycle and in this case controlling refreshing data , you can add this code:

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
   if (refreshing){
       dispatch(clearData())
       dispatch(fetchUsersData())
       dispatch(fetchUser())
       dispatch(fetchUserPosts()) 
       dispatch(
          fetchFollowingUsersPosts()
       )

       setRefreshing(false);
   };
} , [refreshing])
```

Also change your **onRefresh** to:

```
const onRefresh = React.useCallback(() => {
    setRefreshing(true);
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `extraData` prop in Flatlist.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the extraData, how do I get that? Is it one the same way that get my "orginaldata"?

Answer (score 0):

According to the FlatList docs, re-renders can be caused by passing extraData={this.state} to FlatList.

```
<FlatList 
  extraData={this.state.index}
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  removeClippedSubviews={false}
  data={this.props.response}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
  renderItem={({item, index}) => this.renderFlatListItem (item, index)}
/>
```

Now update it like this

```
this.setState(prevState => ({index: prevState.index + 1}));
```